# How can I expand a div to compensate for removing the bordering div's margin?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap's responsive grid layout. I need to adjust one spot on the page so that there's no margin between two columns; the left column has a bottom border that I need to bring right up to the left border of the right column.

**How can I expand a div to compensate for removing the right-bordering div's left margin?**

Things I've been able to do:

- I'm able to dynamically set the height of the left div to drop the bottom border to where I want it: `$('#indented_block .border-bottom').height( $('#indented_block').height()-3 );`
- I'm able to determine the original width of the left div: `$('#indented_block .border-bottom').width()`
- I'm able to determine the left-margin of the right div: `$('#indented_block .border-side').css('margin-left');`
- I'm able to set the left-margin of the right div: `$('#indented_block .border-side').css('margin-left',0);`

I'm not able to use the jQuery `.width()` method to add the original width to the left-margin: `$('#indented_block .border-bottom').width( $('#indented_block .border-bottom').width()+$('#indented_block .border-side').css('margin-left'));`
Rather, I'm not able to *accurately* add those values together (for some reason the above line sets the width to be about the width of the screen).

I've created a [JSFiddle with all the relevant HTML, JS and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/URwY4/).

Comment: Please stop searching "Enter link description here" and making tiny edits that are quite useless. It clogs up the review queue. If you're going to make an edit, actually improve the post. (also posted [here (link)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167332/enter-link-description-here-edit-spam))

Comment: Not substantially. The improvements are quite minor and waste reviewers' time.

Comment: Yes, but many of the posts are a couple years old. These edits don't really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the difference between `$('#indented_block .border-side')`'s `.outerWidth(true)` and `.outerWidth(true)` is the left-margin in a unit that can be used by `.width()`.

So I fixed it using this jQuery:

```
var margin_gap=Math.floor( $('#indented_text').outerWidth(true)-$('#indented_text').outerWidth() );
$('#indented_block .border-bottom').height( $('#indented_block').height()-3 ).width( $('#indented_block .border-bottom').width()+margin_gap );
$('#indented_block .border-side').css('margin-left',0);
```

See [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/URwY4/14/).